# Change /n to <br /> in text from textarea

Tags: jquery, textarea, newline, break

**On dblclick** - DIV is replaced with TEXTAREA. You can edit text.

**On blur** - TEXTAREA is replaced back with DIV. And new line are replaced with "<**br** />".

**First problem** - is in edited text - "<**br** />" is not like breaked or new line in text, but just like text "<**br** />". How to fix it ?

**Second problem**  - there is one "<**br** />" in example. When you edit text in example for the first time, this "<**br** />" is not changed to new line, but only to simple space (**&nsbp;**).  Why there is this error, when you try edit text original for the first time ?

[**jsFiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ynternet/euxeV/)

HTML

```
<div id="meText">Click to edit <br /> this text.</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("#meText").live('click',function(){
        var originalDiv = this;
        $(this).replaceWith($("<textarea></textarea>").text($(this).text().replace(/<br\s?\/?>/g,"\n")).width($(this).width()).height($(this).height()).blur(function(){$(this).replaceWith($(originalDiv).text($(this).val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />")));}));
    });
});
```

Comment: @Partik is my ans working for you..??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with .**html**() instead of .**text**() and change the **replace** like

```
$(function(){
$("#meText").on('click',function(){
    var originalDiv = this;
    $(this).replaceWith($("<textarea></textarea>").html($(this).text().replace(/\n/g, "<br />")));
  });
});
```

See this [**LINK**](http://jsfiddle.net/euxeV/2/).You can add your width and height to this

Comment: Thank you, you was right about **text()** and **html()**, but your example does not work. When I dblclik to edit - there is still the same error.

Answer (score 1):

please use below code

```
  $(this).replaceWith($("<textarea></textarea>").text($(this).html().replace(/<br\s?\/?>/g,"\n")).width($(this).width()).height($(this).height()).blur(function(){$(this).replaceWith($(originalDiv).html($(this).val().replace(/\r\n|\r|\n/g,"<br />")));}));
```

you are using some place text() instead of html(). if we use text() it eliminate html tag